# when using react router the default home page is not constant it is changing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I created a page using `react-router-dom`. On that I set a navbar and on that navbar I put two links (FormControl, Accordion). When the user will click that link the main body will change, nav bar should not change, it should remain constant on the page.

I tried to fix the issue and I am expecting that when a user clicks the links the navbar will not change.

```
import Accordion from "./component/Accordion";
import FormControl from "./component/FormControl";
import NavBar from "./component/NavBar";
import NoPage from "./component/NoPage";
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<NavBar />} />
        <Route path="/Accordion" element={<Accordion />} />
        <Route path="/FormControl" element={<FormControl />} />
        <Route path="/*" element={<NoPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[`app.js`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upeVX.png)
[`index.js`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jnbfz.png)
[`main nav bar`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGG2J.png)
[`when clicking on form control the nav bar get hidden`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lg5mB.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `NavBar` component to renders *always*, or at least consistently with a group of routes you should render it alone on its own route. With `NavBar` rendered on `"/"` when the user navigates to any other route the `"/"` will no longer be the matched route and the `NavBar` component will be unmounted.

### Examples

Unconditionally rendered on its own.

```
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <NavBar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={/* Need a home page component? */} />
        <Route path="/accordion" element={<Accordion />} />
        <Route path="/formcontrol" element={<FormControl />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<NoPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}
```

As part of a [layout route](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#layout-routes) that renders an [`Outlet`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#outlets) component for nested routes.

```
import { Routes, Route, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const AppLayout = () => (
  <>
    <NavBar />
    <Outlet />
  </>
);

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<AppLayout />}>
        <Route index element={/* Need a home page component? */} />
        <Route path="accordion" element={<Accordion />} />
        <Route path="formcontrol" element={<FormControl />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<NoPage />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
}
```